# Styling Only Radio Inputs Within a Two-Level Deep Div

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have a containing div that has three divs inside. I want to style only the two divs that contain the radio input. Without using class names, is it possible to select those two divs?

If not, how do I select just the radio inputs and style those? Here's my attempt, with non-working CSS:

```css
.container > div > input[type="radio"] {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> 
    <input type="radio" id="22" name="SetFour">
    <label for="22"><span>Selection One</span></label>
  </div>
  <div>Some Random Div</div>
  <div> 
    <input type="radio" id="23" name="SetFour">
    <label for="23"><span>Selection Two</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/NWveRmR) for reference

Comment: Q: I have a containing div that has three divs inside. I want to style only the two divs that contain the radio input.  A: The easiest approach is to create a CSS class.  Q: Without using class names.  A: Why???  What's the problem with using CSS classes in this scenario?

Comment: Am I reading this wrong or is this just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?

Answer (score 1):

The selector selects the radio buttons, but the radio inputs don’t support the `border` property.
In case you want to select the divs, not the inputs, use classes; although there is a `:has()` pseudo‐class in the specifications, no major browser currently supports it.
https://caniuse.com/css-has
https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#relational

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-of-type. But do this only if you have no alternatives and are sure that this block will not change in the future.

```
.container > div:nth-of-type(1),
.container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
   border:1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set them a class.
write the similar class and styling.
or their id.